# llvmpy on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, llvm

I am trying to install llvmpy on ubuntu 14.04.

```
uname -a 
Linux -esktop 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

sudo pip install llvmpy fails.  The end of the output is

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/llvmpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7HvRcB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/llvmpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have llvm version 3.4 installed.  The full output is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/8074574/ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

llvmpy requires llvm 3.3 at the moment.  This is available, but not the default on Ubuntu 14.04 (which defaults to the newer llvm 3.4).  First, install llvm3.3:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.3 llvm-3.3-runtime
```

Then, we need to tell pip to use the older llvm.

```
sudo sh -c "LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.3 pip install llvmpy"
```

The above should also work for python3 using pip3

Comment: I had to `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.3 llvm-3.3-runtime llvm-3.3-dev` . (+1 for the oneliner version fix)

Comment: This answer should really be part of the numba install guide. Installing anything these days seems like such a hassle. Few things work "out of the box" (ie. without a stackoverflow answer).